# The resource you requested could not be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating an endpoint using Express to return comments or review from a movie based on the movie id. As you can see in my first route, the ID is passed manually, and data from TheMovieDB is returned. I don't want to have to hardcode the ID, so I tried making it dynamic in my second route.

Prefilled :

```
app.get('/comments/', (req, res) => {
    request('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/401478/reviews?api_key={key}', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred and handle it
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        res.send(body)
    });
});
```

Dynamically:

```
app.get('/comments/:id', (req, res) => {
const id = req.params.id;
    request('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + id +'/reviews?api_key={key}', function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred and handle it
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        res.send(body)
    });
});
```

when I use pre-filled method and request:

```
localhost:8000/comments/
```

I get the correct response (comments + review)

When I use the dynamic route like so:

```
localhost:8000/comments/351286
```

I get the following response: `{"status_code":34,"status_message":"The resource you requested could not be found."}`

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: This is an error from the downstream API.  Your code does not handle errors, and just blindly sends them along.

Comment: The error you're getting implies you're trying to access nonexisting data. Have you tried accessing the same id as your hardcoded snippet? ```localhost:8000/comments/401478```

Comment: @unfortunatelly that returns me a movie object not a comment or review

Answer (score 0):

The errors list can be found [here](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api/status-codes).
You should handle requests this way:

```
app.get('/comments/:id', (req, res) => {
const {id} = req.params;
    request('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + id +'/reviews?api_key={key}', function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) return error;
        if (!reponse) res.send("No themoviedb API response!");
        else {
            swicth (response.statusCode) {
                case 200:
                    res.send(body);
                    break;
                case 501:
                    res.send("Invalid service: this service does not exist");
                    breal;
                //more status codes...
                default:
                    res.send("Generic error");
            }
        }
    });
});
```